# Cannot import package ImageDataGeneratornp.random.seed

Tags: import

I am getting syntax error when trying to import a package in python.  The syntax I am using is "from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGeneratornp.random.seed(22)"

What am I doing wrong?   Any help will be trully appreciated

I tried to import the package and expected a successfull importation